# In VScode, I can just choose program language but can't choose the interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I build docker containers in the remote linux server, and I use vscode extensions,"dev container" and "remote ssh" in my laptop to access the container in the remote server.
I build and connect the container successfully, but the moment that I want to choose the python interpreter at, my vscode doesn't seem to detect my interpreter.[the interface like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY3ti.png) and from the image can know that there isn't "{}" to the left of the word python at the status bar.

When I type "interpreter " in command palette, I can't also find command,"Python: Select Interpreter" [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxT5p.jpg). But I can still use python in bash normally but I don't know why I can't choose python interpreter and run python file in vscode by pushing run button at right-bottom corner.

How can I fix the problem? Thanks for answering!

Comment: Did you install the Python extension?

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for your reminder,  I found the problem should be that the remote server can't include those extensions into containers even though I use the .devcontainer.json , so I must reinstall those extensions in dev container, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code runs extensions in one of two places: locally on the UI / client side, or remotely on the SSH host. While extensions that affect the VS Code UI, like themes and snippets, are installed locally, most extensions will reside on the SSH host. This ensures you have smooth experience and allows you to install any needed extensions for a given workspace on an SSH host from your local machine. This way, you can pick up exactly where you left off, from a different machine complete with your extensions.

If you install an extension from the Extensions view, it will automatically be installed in the correct location. Once installed, you can tell where an extension is installed based on the category grouping.

You can read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh#_managing-extensions) for more details.